# Is it possible to combine HERE document and redirection to write to file without spawning process in Bash?

Tags: bash, stdout, io-redirection, heredoc

Is it possible to combine HERE document and redirection to write to file without spawning process in Bash?

The standard solution involve `cat` command, it is a separate process, not a built-in command:

```sh
cat >my.cfg <<EOF
user = 'me'
dir = "$PWD"
EOF
```

`echo` can be used, but quoting and repetition are involved (HERE document simplifies quoting!):

```sh
echo "user = 'me'" >>my.cfg
echo "dir = "'"'"$PWD"'"' >>my.cfg
```

There is another echo style with multiline quotation and still quoting complicates code a bit:

```sh
echo "user = 'me'
dir = \"$PWD\"" >my.cfg
```

I am particularly looking for a solution that doesn't rely on **fork()** using some Bash tricks + HERE document to avoid quoting issues (except of quoting `$` sign)...

Comment: Why? `cat` is not an expensive program.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Consider Cygwin, which doesn't have efficient `fork`. Again - question is about avoidance  of `fork`.

Comment: Are you doing this in a critical loop where it causes a bottleneck?

Comment: Why would you use `bash` in the first place if you have such severe performance requirements?

Comment: I thought maybe `$(<<EOF ... EOF)` would work, but it doesn't. I'm not sure there's a solution

Comment: Cygwin's fork should be REALLY slow if forking a single cat is expected to be slower that *whatever* you do to copy a file in bash. But, yes, you can do a `while read` loop instead of `cat` -- all in bash ;-)

Comment: If you're so worried about performance, using a heredoc is probably not a great idea -- they create temporary files on disk, after all.

Comment: Better just to `printf '%s\n' $'user = \'me\'' $'dir = "$PWD"' >my.cfg`

Comment: (Also, don't repeat `>>my.cfg` if you care about speed: every time you use the redirection syntax the output file gets reopened. You can open it just once and hold it for multiple commands with `{ cmd1; cmd2; } >outfile`, which also lets you use a regular redirection with `O_TRUNC` because the open and truncation only happen _once_, before the first content-generating command).

Comment: Subprocesses aren't the enemy.  In fact, in some cases they can give really nice parallelism.

Answer (score 4):

This use built-in printf, so no forking or spawning a process

```sh
printf 'user = %q\ndir = %q\n' 'me' "$PWD" >my.cfg
```

Or:

```sh
printf 'user = %q
dir = %q
' 'me' "$PWD" >my.cfg
```

Comment: I like your idea. Some drawbacks are: quoting requirements are moved to need of escaping `'` and `%`...

Answer (score 0):

I thought on the problem. We need something that works like `cat`. I know `read` built-in and it can be done as (copied from deleted hidden answer, still it is valid):

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done >my.cfg <<EOF
user = 'me'
dir = "$PWD"
EOF
```

The solution is not elegant. It is important to have redirection on `while` loop to avoid opening file each iteration!